# vercel deployment failed with "Cannot find module 'typescript' from '/vercel/path0/node_modules'"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vercel

My project is built with React and TypeScript.
I encountered the following error while trying to deploy with Vercel
I tried to "npm install -g typescript" and "npm link typescript" .... etc
But, It doesn't work for me... Please help me

```
$ react-scripts build
/vercel/path0/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:113
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'typescript' from '/vercel/path0/node_modules'
    at Function.resolveSync [as sync] (/vercel/path0/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:111:15)
    at getModules (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-scripts/config/modules.js:119:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-scripts/config/modules.js:142:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js:28:17) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
Node.js v18.16.1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
```

And This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "apple",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/eslint-plugin": "^11.11.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.39",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "recoil": "^0.7.7",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "fix": "npx eslint src --ext .ts,.tsx,.js --fix"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@emotion/eslint-plugin": "^11.11.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.61.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.61.0",
    "eslint": "^8.44.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

please help me!! I would appreciate your assistance.